# Login page fault

Tags: asp.net

I had login Page and it worked well but remember me check box didn't work well and I couldn't know where the error please anyone help me this is my code

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    public TextBox Usertxt,Passwordtxt;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Usertxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
    Passwordtxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["Mycookie"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie Cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Mycookie");
            Usertxt.Text=Cookie.Values["UserName"];
            Passwordtxt.Text=Cookie.Values["Password"];


        }
    }

}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Usertxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
    Passwordtxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");
    Literal LBL;

    LBL = (Literal)Login1.FindControl("FailureText");

    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Usertxt.Text, Passwordtxt.Text))
    {
        Response.Redirect("");

    }
    else
    {
        Login1.FindControl("FailureText");
        LBL.Text = "error ocurred";
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you more I got the answer and this the right code

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public TextBox Usertxt, Passwordtxt;
    public Literal LBL;
    public CheckBox CHB;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Usertxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
    Passwordtxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["MyCookie"] != null)
        {
            HttpCookie Cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("MyCookie");
            Usertxt.Text = Cookie.Values["UserName"];
            Passwordtxt.Text = Cookie.Values["Password"];
        }
    }

}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    Usertxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("UserName");
    Passwordtxt = (TextBox)Login1.FindControl("Password");
    CHB = (CheckBox)Login1.FindControl("RememberMe");
    LBL = (Literal)Login1.FindControl("FailureText");

    HttpCookie MyCookie = new HttpCookie("MyCookie");
    bool IsRememberme = CHB.Checked;
    if (IsRememberme)
    {
        MyCookie.Values.Add("UserName", Usertxt.Text);
        MyCookie.Values.Add("Password", Passwordtxt.Text);
        MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);

    }
    else
    {
        MyCookie.Values.Add("UserName", string.Empty);
        MyCookie.Values.Add("Password", string.Empty);
        MyCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(MyCookie);




    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Usertxt.Text, Passwordtxt.Text))
    {

        Response.Redirect("");

    }
    else
    {
        Login1.FindControl("FailureText");
        LBL.Text = "error ocurred";
    }


}
```

}